# How to copy an array to another array with one property which is an object

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array like this one:

```
"data": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "uuid": "1",
        "date": "2022-01-25",
        "channel": "Teste1",
        "campaign": "teste1",
      },
      "received": 41683,
      "enqueued": 0,
    },
    {
       "_id": {
        "uuid": "1",
        "date": "2022-01-26",
        "channel": "Teste2",
        "campaign": "teste2",
      },
      "received": 314670,
      "enqueued": 0,
    },
]
```

I want to create or destructing this array and create something like this:

```
"data": [
    {
      "_id": {
         "uuid": "1",
        "date": "2022-01-25",
        "channel": "Teste1",
        "campaign": "teste1",
      },
    },
    {
       "_id": {
        "uuid": "2",
        "date": "2022-01-26",
        "channel": "Teste2",
        "campaign": "teste2",
      },
    },
]
```

How can I copy it? how can I use destructuring on this array?

Comment: You can use an [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to go through each of the items in the array and change it's structure as you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.map` through the array, return only `_id` node of each object

```js
const data = [
  {
    "_id": { "uuid": "1", "date": "2022-01-25", "channel": "Teste", "campaign": "teste" },
    "received": 41683,
    "enqueued": 0,
  },
  {
    "_id": { "uuid": "1", "date": "2022-01-25", "channel": "Teste", "campaign": "teste"},
    "received": 314670,
    "enqueued": 0,
  },
];
const output = data.map((item) => {
  const { _id } = item;
  return { _id }
});
console.log(output);
```

OR Simply select `_id` node and return it as below.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "_id": { "uuid": "1", "date": "2022-01-25", "channel": "Teste", "campaign": "teste" },
    "received": 41683,
    "enqueued": 0,
  },
  {
    "_id": { "uuid": "1", "date": "2022-01-25", "channel": "Teste", "campaign": "teste"},
    "received": 314670,
    "enqueued": 0,
  },
];
const output = data.map(({ _id }) => ({ _id }));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map()` you can

```js
const data = [
  {
    "_id": { "uuid": "1", "date": "2022-01-25", "channel": "Teste", "campaign": "teste" },
    "received": 41683,
    "enqueued": 0,
  },
  {
    "_id": { "uuid": "1", "date": "2022-01-25", "channel": "Teste", "campaign": "teste"},
    "received": 314670,
    "enqueued": 0,
  },
];

let result = data.map(e =>{
  return { _id: e._id }
})

console.log(result);
```